# Python: How can I define a path to folder with variable in path

Tags: python, variables, filepath

i want to use this code to Remove the Bookmarks file to replace it with another file later on.

i use.

```
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()
```

to get the user name and then i want to use.

```
os.remove(r"C:\Users\xy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks")
```

But i can't figure out how to replace the xy with the variable use. I have tried to work with %s but without success.

I'd like to do it in Python because it's part of a larger project I'm working on.

Comment: `path = f'some/{user}/in/the/path'`, or `'some/user/path'.replace('user', user)`, or `re.sub('user', user, path)` or any other number of ways, including `'some/%s/path' % user`

Comment: `os.remove(f"C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks")`

Comment: Thanks for the quick Help. I know this is a tiny problem for many but sometimes I waste hours on the dumbest problems.